# Joomla Migration from 1.5 to 2.5

Tags: joomla, migration, joomla2.5, joomla1.5

I am migrating one of my websites from Joomla 1.5 to 2.5 version with the help of a component called jUpgrade. My Joomla 1.5 has got the following componets installed

Artio JoomSEF

Akeeba Backup

Docman

Dt Register

JCE Administration

jComments

Jevents

Joomla Pack

jVideo

Lyften Bloggie

Phoca SEF

Tienda

Virtuemart

xmap

So I would like to migrate these components also.

Now I have done a migration using jUpgrade and it has migrated all the core components and files. Also it has copied the templates. I am using gantry and my default template is    rt_mercado_j15. These templates are however not showing in the template manager. Also how can I migrate the third party components to the new site, otherwise I will loose the data.

Answer (score 4):

JUpgrade only updates the Joomla Core. You'll have to update the extensions yourself.

Steps before upgrading:

- Check if you have the latest 1.5 version (1.5.25)
- Check if all you extensions have a 2.5 version available (http://extensions.joomla.org/)
- Check if you template is available in 2.5
- Backup you Joomla installation and database (with XCloner or Akeeba Backup for example)
- Try to update a test installation with the same extensions (you could for example run a local version from you backup and see if it works)

Please visit the [Joomla Docs Migration Guide](http://docs.joomla.org/Migrating_from_Joomla_1.5_to_Joomla_2.5) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

JUpgrade only updates the core Joomla files, extensions and database tables. It doesn't do the 3rd party extension or templates, therefore you will have to download the Joomla 2.5 compatible versions of each one.

Comment: I can download the extensions , but how can I migrate the extension data over. If I install the new extensions, it will wipe out the data in the tables which is already migrated ?

Comment: Maybe you could backup your database, upgrade your Joomla, install updated extensions and then restore the extension data from the backup.

Note: It's possible that the data-structure has changed for some extension.

Comment: you should be able to install the 2.5 compatible extension ontop of the old ones. you won't lose any data this way